# open a link in new tab in selenium

Tags: selenium

I am trying to open a link in new tab.

### Trial1

```
Actions action = new Actions(Driver).KeyDown(Keys.Control).KeyDown(Keys.Shift).Click(FindElement(xxx).KeyUp(Keys.Control).KeyUp(Keys.Shift);
         action.Build().Perform();
```

This code opens the link in new tab at the same time opens another blank window

### Trial2 - right click the link and choose the first option "open link new tab"

```
      action.ContextClick(FindElement(xxx).SendKeys(Keys.ArrowDown).SendKeys(Keys.Enter).Build().Perform();
```

This opens the link in new window instead of new tab

Comment: change/add attribute of link to `target="_blank"` and link will open in new tab.

Answer (score 0):

So what you need to do is first open a new tab using JS executor:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open()");
```

or

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open('the new link here', '_blank')");
```

If you did not use the secon method continue with the following: switch to the new window and navigate to the link

```
driver.switchTo().window(here the window handle);
driver.get("here is the link");
```

Comment: but the url will be dynamic

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you want to open multiple url at once?

Comment: If that is the case, you can still use the above method, you will have to save the current windows handle as a string and come back to that window each time you need.

Comment: A better approach could be that you provide the link directly in the ```window.ope("url)```